# How can I increase a CSS property's value repeatedly on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin

I want to add (in this case, decrease, technically) the value of an element each time a different element is clicked. What I have so far:

```
$("#trigger_heritage").click(function () {
  $(".heritage_content ul").css("margin-left", + -880);
  // So each time clicking shall move the .heritage_content ul-element 880px further left
});
```

It gets `880px` far left, but only once. What I want is that this value gets increased each time the other element gets clicked.

How would I do that?

Comment: Use `.css("margin-left", "-=880px")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var move = 0;
    $(".left").click(function () {
        move -= 25;
        $(".move").css("margin-left", move + "px");
    });
    $(".right").click(function () {
        move += 25;
        $(".move").css("margin-left", move + "px");
    });
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjfjahjo/

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a string in the format `-=[value]` to the `css()` method which you can use to amend the current value. Try this:

```
$("#trigger_heritage").click(function () {
    $(".heritage_content ul").css("margin-left", '-=880');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rz7cmvn2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable, say `$marginLeft`, and increment this each time the function is called, then set the `margin-left:$marginLeft`....